# Where is the wallpaper folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Where is the wallpaper folder in Windows 7?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

They are in

- `%SystemRoot%\Web\Wallpaper` (default themes)
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` ( any new themes that you might have installed )
- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` ( any other pictures that you might have made as an wallpaper.

Comment: Important info if you want to change the background of your work PC :)

Comment: There are also some in %SystemRoot%\Globalization\MCT\MCT-*

Answer (score 6):

On my version of Windows 7 the Desktop Background folders are located in the directory below:

- C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper

You can create your own folder, add it to the above directory, and then browse to that location to add it to the "Picture Location" dropdown list within the "Choose your desktop background" screen.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by @Sathya is mostly correct, it can also be located elsewhere, in a location defined in a `.theme` text file located in 
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`

For example the well-known image tool Irfanview (1) can directly select the current image as wallpaper, and in that case it will be stored as:

```
%APPDATA%\Irfanview\Irfanview_Wallpaper.bmp
```

(1) Tested with Irfanview 4.38

`