# Filename of current slide on Win10 desktop

Tags: windows-10, filenames, slideshow

Windows 10 desktop is showing a slideshow of random images from a local folder.  How can I find the filename of the current image?

Comment: Does [Path to current desktop background in Windows 10 (Slideshow)?](https://superuser.com/q/1615553) help?

Comment: [How to Find the Current Wallpaper File Name and Path in Windows 10/11](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-current-wallpaper-file-path-windows-10/#powershell)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot create a slideshow displaying filenames, with Windows' own slideshow. However, it's easy, using a free) third party tool, such as [*ArtSage](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/artsage.html) or [*IrfanView*](https://www.irfanview.com/), to create a slideshow that displays filenames. Let it run full-screen in the background, and any other program can run in the foreground, covering part of the image.

Note that *ArtSage* eschews standard menus and relies on using <kbd>F1</kbd> for its context (popup) menu. *ArtSage* makes it easy to create a slideshow, though it is not a general-purpose image editor.

[image: ArtSage Context Menu]

*IrfanView* is a general-purpose image editor with a plethora of additional capabilities, including slideshows. After installing *IrfanView* (or using the portable version):

[image: IrfanView slideshow]

1. Create a slideshow by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> for the *Slideshow* dialog, and selecting files from the dialog.
2. Click *Add* to add selected files, or *Add all* to add all files in that folder. Repeat selection from additional folders, if desired. Note that items in subfolders are *not* added; those folders must be selected manually.
3. Click *Save filename as TXT file* in a convenient location.
4. Set the parameters for the display of the next show:

   a. Select *Show text*, and use `$D$F` to show the full filename and path, or `$F` for just the filename.

   b. Select the order and delay between images.

   c. Set *Loop slideshow* to run continuously.

   d. Click *Play slideshow* to test it.
5. Create a shortcut to *IrfanView*, and add the following [command-line arguments](https://irfanview-forum.de/forum/program/command-line-and-scripts/wishes-and-questions/10963-) at the end: **slideshow=[image_list.txt]**, where the text file containing the paths and filenames from step 3. For example,

`"C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" /slideshow "C:\Slides\slideshow.txt"`

Play the slideshow, full-screen, and it will run in the background, while you run other applications in the foreground to browse the web, read your mail, etc. BTW, to pause the *IrfanView* slideshow, or go back or forth, so you can copy the filename, use the <kbd>Pause</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> keys.

Comment: The OP is referring to the slideshow that Windows 10 does on the desktop, not its slideshow screen saver.

Comment: Thanx, but I don't want a screensaver.  I like having the background change to a new photo every minute while I work.  If it looks interesting around the edges, I can minimize my work and admire the view, then get back to work.  (In my retirement, I don't do any work that's time-critical.)   But once in a while I feel the need to share the photo with a friend or tweak it in Photoshop, and then I'd like to know its name.  I get tired of leafing thru 1800+ thumbnails to find it.)

Comment: @NickJones, the answer has been changed to one for a slideshow running full-screen, i.e., as a background image.