# Where are Windows 10 previously used background images stored (Path/Source)?

Tags: windows, windows-10

This is different from the numerous previously asked questions about desktop background image's path. The question is exactly same as the title.

I want previously used desktop background's path. 
It is like this for more detail -[Where the first image is desktop background and others are previously used ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Giywk.png) (link to the image). The first one is desktop background while rest four images are previously used. I want to know the path of rest four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out later.

The path is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers`
in regedit. Reference: [How to delete a desktop wallpaper in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1265170/how-to-delete-a-desktop-wallpaper-in-windows-10?rq=1)
 answered by [Magnus](https://superuser.com/users/731090/magnus).