# Rercover picture from desktop background

Tags: windows-10

I saved one of my own favourite pictures (from my pictures folder) as a desktop background. Now the original has been accidentally erased from my pictures folder. Can I recover it from my desktop background?

Comment: Have a look at this [Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/966650/302907).

Answer (score 0):

Look in C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\ and the folders there to see if you can find your picture. That is the default location and working on my Windows 10 machine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you. The path to the current desktop picture is in the registry HKEY_USERS \  \ Control Panel \ Desktop
or
HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Control Panel \ Desktop
REG_SZ value "WallPaper"