# Where is the current desktop background stored

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In which file would the desktop background be stored, I have checked desktop.ini, but that only shows two dll files in C:/windows/system32/

I'm using windows 10.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/where-is-the-current-custom-wallpaper-stored-in/f08a364c-43d3-4303-9252-81d88b2b86a7

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Path 1 -
`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles`

Path 2 -
`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper`

You may refer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/966650/path-to-current-desktop-backgrounds-in-windows-10)