# Where is the default user account images folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Similar to this question:
[Where is the wallpaper folder in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/207852/where-is-the-wallpaper-folder-in-windows-7)

But I'm looking for the location of the default user account images (such as the flower in the image below):

[image: windows 7 user account image example]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this directory:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Default Pictures
```

Note that the `ProgramData` folder is hidden and not visible by default.

If you rename/replace `user.bmp` (by default, the flower image in Windows 7) with a different image of the same name and dimensions, it will replace all the user account photos by default.

Comment: The contents of this folder got erased when I upgraded to Windows 10 1803