# How to find the places of the wall paper images?

Tags: images, desktop

When starting the computer windows shows those beautful landscape photos on the welcome  screen. Some laptops indicate the place but on my laptop I can’t find any information.
What do I have to do?

Comment: Are you asking about the Windows 10 "Spotlight" images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the wallpaper folder in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/207852/where-is-the-wallpaper-folder-in-windows-7)

Comment: `C:\Windows\Web` is typically used on modern Windows for wallpapers, etc. `This PC > Local Disk (C:) > Users > [YOUR USERNAME] > AppData > Local >  Packages > Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy > LocalState > Assets` is used for Windows 10 Spotlight Lockscreen papers, I believe. You may have to turn on Hidden Files and Folders to view it though.

Comment: Check out this [article](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/save-windows-10-spotlight-lock-screen-pictures/).

Comment: By "place", do you mean where the image file is stored on your computer, or the geographic location where the photo was taken?

Answer (score -1):

Find a Photo icon and the link "Like what you see" in the top right corner of Lock screen and hover mouse over them. It will display information about the image, including place.

Comment: I know. it works on the other laptop but not on mine :(